# How I can change rows places in datadridview?

Tags: c#, winforms

Good afternoon, dear developers.
Faced such a problem:
there is DataGridVev, I have data lines in it. Depending on the toss-up, I need to sort the order of the rows in the display.
How can I do that?
As I understand the lines do not have an index, and the columns have.

Here is my code for sorting

```
for(int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
{
    int tmp = i;
    foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
    {
        if ((string)row.Cells[2].Value == position[i])
        {             
            Console.WriteLine(position[i] + "Место: " + tmp);
            tmp += 9;
        }
    }
}
```

copied from the comment of the OP:

```
con = new SqlConnection(); 
con.ConnectionString = getConn; 
con.Open(); 
adap = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM " + table_name + " WHERE Groupe_year = @year ", con); 
string year = comboBox1.Text;    
adap.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@year", year); 
ds = new System.Data.DataSet(); 
adap.Fill(ds, "Fighters_Details"); 
dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
```

Comment: rows have indices. `.Index` property. and `dataGridView1.Rows` collection also support indices: `dataGridView1.Rows[0]`, `dataGridView1.Rows.Insert(idx, ...)`

Comment: how does the data get into your `DataGridView` ? would it not be wiser to sort the underlying data collection ?=! and the redisplay it?

Comment: con = new SqlConnection();
con.ConnectionString = getConn;
con.Open();

            adap = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM " + table_name + " WHERE Groupe_year = @year ", con);

            string year = comboBox1.Text;
            adap.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@year", year);
            ds = new System.Data.DataSet();
            adap.Fill(ds, "Fighters_Details");
            dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];

Comment: so I would suggest to sort the `ds.Tables[0]` and hook it again to the `dataGridView1.DataSource`. Do you know how to do it?

Comment: Yes, I know. Thanks guys.

Comment: please edit your question and write the extra info from your comment there. Code is unreadable in comments

Comment: Be carefull with using Parameters.AddWithValue(). Read this https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/

Answer (score 0):

Assign the Data Source to a Data View instead.

```
dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0].DefaultView;
```

For Sorting on the Groupe_year column as an example:

```
((System.Data.DataView)dataGridView1.DataSource).Sort = "Groupe_year";
```